# TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have seen this error mentioned in regards to string arrays but not actual strings. I have a TypeScript file with the line

```
if (!bus.lineInfo.PublishedLineName.includes(input)) {
```

This gives me an error of

```
TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

`bus` is a variable that implements the `bus` interface:

```
interface bus {
    "lineInfo": {
        "PublishedLineName": string,
        "DestinationName": string, // The headsign of the bus
        "Color": string,
        "TextColor": boolean | string // false if this is "FFFFFF", otherwise it's the color
    },
    "warnings": boolean | busWarnings
    "marker"?: google.maps.Marker,
    "result"?: JQuery // The search result that appears in the sidebar
}
```

`lineInfo.PublishedLineName` is declared as a `string`, and `String.prototype.includes()` [is a function according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), so why does the TypeScript compiler complain about the missing property/method?

Comment: What is includes or what do you think it is?

Comment: I believe it is a string method; I've updated my post to reflect that along with a link

Comment: What are the "target" and "lib" settings in your `tsconfig.json`?  `String.includes` is in ES6.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen "target" is set to `es5`. I don't have a "lib" option set. Setting "lib" to "es2015" removes the string error but causes a bunch of errors in thea jQuery d.ts file I have from DefinitelyTyped.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should add es2016 or es7 `lib` complierOptions in tsconfig.json. Default TypeScript doesn't support some es6 polyfill functions

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": [
       "dom",
       "es7"
    ]
  }
}
```

Or change build target to es2016 if you no longer want to support ES5 anymore

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target" "es2016"
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Can you please explain what "dom" does/includes support for?

Comment: `dom` support frontend interface (DOM, Event...). Some library is used for both frontend and backend, when compiling it will alert syntax error. If you develop backend, and there is no error when compiling, you can remove it

Comment: This does not work in VSCode with Typescript 3.2.2. Has something changed in the last few months?

Comment: I'm facing same problem. Have you found anything in this regard @LarsNyström

Comment: No, I was in over my head so I decided to stay away from TS for now.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Add `es2016.array.include` to `compilerOptions.lib`