# Property 'matchAll' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: typescript, angular7

I want to apply Reg Expression on string. In order to get all groups result i am using matchAll method. Here is my code

```
const regexp = RegExp('foo*','g'); 
const str = "table football, foosball";
let matches = str.matchAll(regexp);

for (const match of matches) {
   console.log(match);
}
```

during compiling on above code i got error

> Property 'matchAll' does not exist on type '"table football, foosball"'

during searching about this error i found similar issue on stackoverflow

[TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811239/ts2339-property-includes-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

I changed tsconfig configuration as mention in above link but my issue did not solved

Here is my tsconfig code;

```
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
 "baseUrl": "./",
 "importHelpers": true,
 "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "declaration": false,
 "module": "es2015",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "target": "es2016",
 "typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
 ],
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) is part of the ECMAScript 2020 specification (draft).
In TypeScript you can include these library features by adding `es2020` or `es2020.string`, in the compiler options:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2020.string"]
}
```

Comment: i have just added this as i was having the same issues as OP. But i now get the following error in my cli console. .matchAll is not a function. Any idea on what might be wrong?

Comment: If you're getting `matchAll is not a function` as a runtime error this might be because your using typescript as a typechecker and using something else (eg webpack + babel) as a transpiler. You'll therefore still need to find a way to polyfil matchAll function

Comment: I got some very weird behaviour with `"lib": ["es2020.string"]` in jsconfig.json.
Using `"target": "es2020"` worked much better.
Also had to change node version in launch.json, for some reason node didn't have matchAll even though vsc claimed it was running v15, no idea how that happened.

Comment: changing target to es2020 solved it for me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Checking the ts signature for the `String` and `RegExp` classes I realized there is no signature for `matchAll`. One manner to solve it could be:

```
let matches = str['matchAll'](regexp);
```

Another way would be adding the method to `lib.es5.d.ts` file
[image]

Comment: so how this code works here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: thnks @SergioEscudero i checked your first suggestion and its working great as expected but strangely its working on chrome browser but on Firefox it through error "str.matchAll is not a function". i will check your second suggestion.

Comment: Check the browser compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@matchAll#Browser_compatibility

Comment: The work around str['matchAll'](regexp) gives error '...because index expression is not of type 'number'.  if Str is a string doesn't str[x] expect a numeric index?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used outdated version of the Node shipped by `apt` package manager (v10.19.0). After I upgraded to the latest (v16.11.1) issue had gone.

Following is summary of commands I used:

```sh
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

sudo n latest
```

The source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version